# sklearn.cross_validate returns one unfitted estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I used `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` for cross-validation of an `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`, which works great.

Now I am interested in the coefficients of a feature selection step in the pipeline. The selector used is `SelectFromModel(LinearSVC(penalty="l1", dual=False))`.

By setting `return_estimator=True` the cross-validation method should return the estimators fitted on each split. This works well for the classifier:

```
>>> pipeline[-1].coef_
[ 0.20973553  0.48124347 -0.27811877 ... ]
```

However, when I inspect the feature selection step, an attribute error is raised, as the object is not yet fitted:

```
>>> output = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, cv=skf.split(X, data.cohort_idx), return_estimator=True)
>>> output['estimator'][1][-2].estimator.coef_
AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

Fitting this step afterwards solves issue, but would be cumbersome and error prone in the `cross_validation` process:

```
>>> pipeline.fit(X, y)
>>> pipeline[3].estimator.coef_
[-0.27501591  0.14398988  0.83767175 ... ]
```

How do I get the `cross_validate` to return a fitted feature selector?

You can replicate this example using:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

# Make dummy data
X = np.random.rand(50, 4)
y = np.random.choice([True, False], 50)

# Make pipeline
selector = SelectFromModel(LinearSVC(penalty="l1", dual=False))
classifier = LogisticRegression()
pipeline = make_pipeline(selector, classifier)

# Cross validate
output = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, return_estimator=True)

# Print coefficients
print('Classifier coef_:', output['estimator'][0][1].coef_)
print('Selector coef_:  ', output['estimator'][0][0].estimator.coef_)
```

Answer (score 0):

After finalizing this question, and just before submitting it, I realized I should access the member `estimator_` and not `estimator`.

I hope this helps someone one day.